# Java Fork Join Pool Timing Issue

Tags: java, concurrency, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I'm trying to implement a Fork Join Pool what will take the children of one node and explore them concurrently. However I think that my fork join pool executes the threads and then shuts down too quickly, causing the threads to stop executing?

So far I have this code:

Main method:

```
    while (!(pqOpen.IsEmpty())) 
    {       
        tempVertex = pqOpen.GetNextItem();        
        if (tempVertex.city == endLocation.city)  
        {
            resetVertex();           
            return tempVertex;         
        }
        else 
        {                            
            ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(tempVertex.neighbors.GetNoOfItems());
            for (int i = 0; i < tempVertex.neighbors.GetNoOfItems(); i++) //for each neighbor of tempVertex
            {
                forkJoinPool.execute(new NeighbourThread(tempVertex, allVertices, routetype, pqOpen, i, endLocation));

            }
            forkJoinPool.shutdown();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my class that it runs:

```
public class NeighbourThread extends RecursiveAction {
    Vertex tempVertex, endLocation;
    VertexHashMap allVertices;
    int routetype, i;
    PriorityQueue pqOpen;   

    public NeighbourThread(Vertex tempVertex, VertexHashMap allVertices, int routetype, PriorityQueue pqOpen, int i, Vertex endLocation)
    {
        this.allVertices = allVertices;
        this.routetype = routetype;
        this.tempVertex = tempVertex;
        this.pqOpen = pqOpen; 
        this.i = i;
        this.endLocation = endLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void compute() {
          Edge currentRoad = tempVertex.neighbors.GetItem(i);                             
          Vertex vertexNeighbour = allVertices.GetValue(currentRoad.toid);   

          if (vertexNeighbour.inClosed)//
              return null;   

          if ((!vertexNeighbour.inOpen) || temp_g_score < vertexNeighbour.getTentativeDistance()) 
          {
              vertexNeighbour.from = tempVertex;
              vertexNeighbour.setTentativeDistance(temp_g_score);                                  

              // if neighbor isn't in open set, add it to open set
              if (!vertexNeighbour.inOpen) 
              {
                  vertexNeighbour.inOpen = true;
                  pqOpen.AddItem(vertexNeighbour);
              }
          }
    }
```

I've removed majority of the code within compute() as I don't feel it's relevant to the problem.

I think the problem is that the forkJoinPool.shutdown() line gets executed before the threads that have been created have finished executing. 
Is there any way to ensure that the threads are finished before I loop back round to the top of the while loop?

Comment: I haven't read too far into your code, but when asking a question it is always a good idea to state clearly what the problem is.  I can kind of infer that your problem is that there is a race between executing your tasks and when you shut down, but not entirely sure. For instance "All the tasks I submitted aren't being executed" etc...

Comment: Hi John, I think you may not have read the bottom of my post, so I'll edit it and ensure that at the top I put the problem description!

Comment: Side note on code quality: naming a method with a generic term (like "compute") ... and then doing many many different things inside that single method ... leads to code that will be **hard** to maintain. See here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/single-responsibility

Comment: I don't see where your task is performing any recursion. This is, only the "main method" is adding any tasks to the `ForkJoinPool`. Is that right? My point is, why are you using `ForkJoinPool` without `fork()` or `join()`?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet you need to `awaitTermination` on the ForkJoinPool after shutting down.  The pool should accept and execute all tasks while it is in `shutdown` phase but won't accept new tasks

`forkJoinPool.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);`

Comment: "*Should accept* and execute all tasks … but *won't accept* new tasks"

Answer (score 0):

You are totally misusing this framework. You are not doing [Data Parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_parallelism) processing. As @erickson said in the above comments, there is no recursion.

What if tempVertex.neighbors.GetNoOfItems() is 1,000? You are going to create 1,000 threads and then shut down the framework; create a new framework on the next iteration of while (!(pqOpen.IsEmpty())), etc. Creating the framework takes quite a bit of overhead. Creating threads takes even more overhead.

I don't like criticizing your work but without knowing all the requirements I cannot give you a better design (that would be constructive criticism.)

Perhaps you should look into a blocking queue with thread pool structure.